# fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp: No such file or directory, no root access

Tags: linux, boost

I am trying to compile BRHCLUS, a package part of OrthoDB. I do not have root access but I did load the module boost. I keep getting the fatal error when trying to make all. Any ideas as to what the issue is?

```
  Compiling pairdataset.cpp
In file included from pairdataset.cpp:22:0:
pairdataset.h:37:10: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp: No     such file or directory
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [.linux/pairdataset.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I did load the module boost*? Where did you install it? You probably need to add `-I<path/to/boost>` to your compiler options.

Comment: I use a university cluster so I have to load modules like python/perl/boost t use them. I know the directory they are in and I checked them for the file that was missing and it was present.

Comment: also, when I use the configure.sh it finds the boost libraries and creates a makefile.config which contains the directories to the boost lib etc. when I use make all for the makefile I get the fatal error.